# Best approach to convert existing video files into mpeg-dash

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, adaptive-bitrate

We have over 50MM videos with an average of 3 different resolution e.g 240, 360 etc.

It is time for us to move to [Dynamic Adaptive Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) or Mpeg-Dash. At the moment our biggest challenge is convert existing data into Mpeg-DASH. Our current approach is to convert all videos one by one and create MPD file, this could take months.

Is there an alternate approach? I am aware of streaming existing files realtime using different tools but this will require Huge CPU resource? Any benchmarks that can help us decide how should we be moving for Mpeg Dash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a huge amount of videos in a short amount of time it might be a good approach to use one of the cloud encoding services available as they can convert multiple files in parallel.

I personally have good experience with bitmovin cloud encoding as I really like their API clients with lots of examples: https://bitmovin.com/encoding/

However, there are other services available as well

- encoding.com
- Zencoder